# Visual Studio 2010: Embed Interop Types

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clr, com-interop, pia

I found some information about this on [Scott Hanselmans Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CLRAndDLRAndBCLOhMyWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx)

Does anybody exactly know what this mean?

Is this only for the Office Primary Interop Assemblies, or can I also use this to Embed my Redemption library or other COM libraries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The process described in Scott Hanselman's blog is called *Type Equivalence*, a rather nebulous term for the CLR 4.0's support for COM interop type assemblies.  Although I haven't had a chance to look at it, there is a video here at Channel 9 that discusses it:

**Raja Krishnaswamy and Vance Morrison: CLR 4 - Inside Type Equivalence**
http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Raja-Krishnaswamy-and-Vance-Morrison-CLR-4-Inside-Type-Equivalence/

Apparently you can write your own "type equivalence" assemblies, and embed them.  Note that this probably does not apply to just any COM assembly; type equivalence assemblies implement an interface called `IApplication`.  See here:

**Advances in .NET Type system: Type Equivalence Demo**
[http://blogs.msdn.com/mshneer/archive/2008/10/28/advances-in-net-type-system-type-equivalence-demo.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mshneer/advances-in-net-type-system-type-equivalence-demo)

Answer (score 1):

One remark about: if you add reference and property "**Embed Interop Types = true** " - this can make some casuistic errors while you compiling : - you see what inside reference have functions and propertyes - but compilator don't find it and generate errors !