# vsto prerequisites how do I know which I need?

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I just created a VSTO Add-In for Office 2010. How how do I know which pre-requisites I need and whether or not my add-in would work for both 2010 and 2007 or just 2010? I'm confused why this seems obvious based on the lack of documentation on this topic. During compilation it tells you if there is a problem if you're building for instance on .NET Client profile instead of the full .NET but for all the other prerequisites I don't know how to tell. Do I need for instance the Visual Studio for Office 2010 Runtime and the Interlop Assemblies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be of interest: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4411365/1373170
and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1596868/1373170

If you are on .NET 4, you don't need to ship PIA anymore, if you use embedded interop assemblies.

The VSTO Runtime would still be required I believe.